# decltype, dyn, impl traits, and how to declare the return type of a function when refactoring

Tags: rust, decltype, actix-web

I'm a Rust newbie, but programming veteran approaching Rust from a C++ point of view/background, so that may explain much of my confusion.

I have at its heart, a mind-numbingly simple problem to solve. And yet what seems the most basic of things in rust has run me into a rats nest of trouble.

I have a bit of code:

```
pub fn my_application(cfg: &mut web::ServiceConfig) {
   let auth = HttpAuthentication::bearer(validate_bearer);
   ...
```

which I wish to refactor. Instead of using the 'actix' HttpAuthentication::bearer middleware, I want to use my own custom middleware.

So *all* I'm trying to do is take the 'let auth = ...' line and put the stuff after the equal sign into a function, in another file.

**How hard could that be?**

So I tried the obvious:
in a new file:

```
// WONT repeat 'use' statements in rest, but included once in case you try to compile)
use actix_web::dev::ServiceRequest;
use actix_web::Error;
use actix_web_httpauth::extractors::bearer::BearerAuth;
use actix_web_httpauth::middleware::HttpAuthentication;
use core::future::Future;
use crate::server::auth::common::validate_bearer;

// in C++, you would might say auto, or some such
pub fn create_auth_middleware_1()
{
    let auth = HttpAuthentication::bearer(validate_bearer);
    auth
}
```

That failed:

```
^^^^ expected `()`, found `HttpAuthentication<BearerAuth, ...>`
```

OK - so Rust has no auto or type deduction for function declarations (or I've missed the syntax for that). Fine.

Next I tried 'generics'

```
pub fn create_auth_middleware_2<T>() -> T
 {
    let auth = HttpAuthentication::bearer(validate_bearer);
    auth
}
```

which results in:

```
^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found `HttpAuthentication<BearerAuth, ...>`
```

Next - tried a series of 'where' clauses on the T to specify it, inspired by the declarations on the service 'wrap' function - a very complicated bit of type declarations. For example:

```
// ONE TIME ADD 'uses' but keep around for other samples that need it...
use actix_service::boxed::{BoxService};
use actix_web::body::MessageBody;
use actix_web::dev::{Payload, Service, ServiceResponse, Transform};
use actix_web::http::header::Header;
use actix_web::{FromRequest, HttpRequest};

pub fn create_auth_middleware_3<T>() -> T
    where T: Transform<S, ServiceRequest>,
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse, Error = Error> {
    let auth = HttpAuthentication::bearer(validate_bearer);
    auth
}
```

maybe a hint from the compiler this time!

```
 auth
   |     ^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found `HttpAuthentication<BearerAuth, ...>`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                      found struct `HttpAuthentication<BearerAuth, fn(..., ...) -> ... {validate_bearer}>`
           the full type name has been written to ....
```

So I tried the actual type the compiler wrote to that file

```
pub fn create_auth_middleware_4() -> HttpAuthentication<BearerAuth, fn(ServiceRequest, BearerAuth) -> impl futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<ServiceRequest, actix_web::Error>> {validate_bearer}> {
    let auth = HttpAuthentication::bearer(validate_bearer);
    auth
}
```

results in:

```
error[E0747]: constant provided when a type was expected
  --> src/server/auth/middleware.rs:37:69
   |
37 | ...h, fn(ServiceRequest, BearerAuth) -> impl futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<ServiceRequest, actix_web::Error>> {validate_bearer}...
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

OK - maybe Rust doesn't like the explicit `{validate_bearer}` stuff it wrote as part of the type.

```
pub fn create_auth_middleware_5() -> HttpAuthentication<BearerAuth, fn(ServiceRequest, BearerAuth) -> impl futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<ServiceRequest, actix_web::Error>> > {
    let auth = HttpAuthentication::bearer(validate_bearer);
    auth
}
```

results in:

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` only allowed in function and inherent method return types, not in `fn` pointer return types
```

This thing I'm trying to do - wrap an expression into a separate function which goes in another file, is completely trivial in just about every programming language I've ever used (Python, prolog, C, C++, Java, Typescript, JavaScript, Ruby, Lisp). I'm sure there is a very simple way to do this in Rust as well, but I've failed to find it. Please help me to see what I'm missing, and how to do this sort of basic factoring of Rust code.

Comment: Maybe you would be interested in [the actual definition of `bearer`](https://docs.rs/actix-web-httpauth/0.8.0/actix_web_httpauth/middleware/struct.HttpAuthentication.html#impl-HttpAuthentication%3CBearerAuth%2C%20F%3E), so that you can see what exactly is the return type of that function.

Comment: it uses 'Self' because its a method of a trait. I'm writing a function, so I don't see how I can do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to do `impl Fn(...) -> impl Future<...>`, but using `impl` twice like this is [currently not allowed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/99697). There is a workaround that is mentioned in [another thread](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/93082) that works for this. This will hopefully be solved by either fully allowing it or by [`type_alias_impl_trait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/type-alias-impl-trait.html) in the future. For now, you can work around it by creating a new trait. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=10bdc3c47c80b32d4bbb287e1363d821)

```rs
pub trait BearerFuture: Fn(ServiceRequest, BearerAuth) -> Self::Fut {
    type Fut: Future<Output = Result<ServiceRequest, (Error, ServiceRequest)>>;
}

impl<F, Fut> BearerFuture for F
where
    F: Fn(ServiceRequest, BearerAuth) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<ServiceRequest, (Error, ServiceRequest)>>,
{
    type Fut = Fut;
}

pub fn create_auth_middleware_5() -> HttpAuthentication<BearerAuth, impl BearerFuture> {
    HttpAuthentication::bearer(validate_bearer)
}
```

There's some nightly features which make these easier. Since these haven't entered stabilization, they are at a minimum 12 weeks from being in stable (1.70 releases today), and will likely take 6 months or more. I would expect `type_alias_impl_trait` to be released first, with high likelihood of being released eventually, since it is incredibly useful for `async` code and seems to cover the uses of `impl_trait_in_fn_trait_return`. I mention these mostly for future readers or those already using nightly. Others should use the new trait method.

With `type_alias_impl_trait`, you could do this. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4957325a9e5e145a8ba4e3f60a2b2e2f)

```rs
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

type BearerFn = impl Fn(ServiceRequest, BearerAuth) -> BearerFuture;
type BearerFuture = impl Future<Output = Result<ServiceRequest, (Error, ServiceRequest)>>;

pub fn create_auth_middleware_5() -> HttpAuthentication<BearerAuth, BearerFn> {
    HttpAuthentication::bearer(validate_bearer)
}
```

And with `impl_trait_in_fn_trait_return` you could create this ugly mess. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=22d3d21556cdc77c8a926edc54fc2cdf)

```rs
#![feature(impl_trait_in_fn_trait_return)]

pub fn create_auth_middleware_5() -> HttpAuthentication<
    BearerAuth,
    impl Fn(
        ServiceRequest,
        BearerAuth,
    ) -> impl Future<Output = Result<ServiceRequest, (Error, ServiceRequest)>>,
> {
    HttpAuthentication::bearer(validate_bearer)
}
```

Note: You will almost never use the `fn` type in rust. You'll usually use one of the [`Fn`/`FnMut`/`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) traits.

Comment: @drewato THANK you for the above amazingly thorough answers. I will review it tomorrow morning, and try and understand it. Thanks again!

Comment: @drewato - I've tested your fix, and studied your response. Your fix works! Thank you!

Comment: @drewato - I do have some remaining questions and suggestions for your response.

Comment: You start by writing 'the ideal solution would be to do impl Fn(...) -> impl Future<...>'. In C++, elipsis like that are part of the language, and LITERALLY what you would write to define something that took arbitrary arguments. That feature doesn't appear in rust (too bad). But your first answer for what would be desirable then is unclear - if you are suggesting the elipsis thing should be part of rust, IS part of rust (and I cannot find on web), or just a short hand for stating 'throw in your args in the right places here'. I assume you meant the later.

Comment: please clarify which of this you are suggesting as 'the ideal world' solution.

Comment: THEN - additionally - you helpfully provided some hints about future rust features that might make this easier and provided VERY helpful playground links. Could you kindly clarify (for the rust newbies like me) when we might expect these features to make it into the language (I know you cannot promise, just provide rough expectations).

Comment: @drewato - fyi - also - what you call the impl_trait_in_fn_trait_return  'ugly mess' - i consider the second best possible solution (only behind elipsis). The reason why, is that your 'preferered' non-ugly solutions require PUBLISHING  (exporting a public) named type that is really not intened, but an artificat of saying something else (publishing the create function). I sympathize with the editorialization labeling that the ugly choice, but I don't agree with it.

Comment: @drewato - OK - I was premature about this being an answer, but cannot unmark it. Well - you DID answer as much of the question as I asked - mostly. But the object that gets returned, I have to USE. And when I try to USE it, it fails.

Comment: @drewwato when I try to use this with the 'route(...).wrap(auth) call I get:    error[E0271]: expected `<impl BearerFuture as BearerFuture>::Fut` to be a future that resolves to `Result<ServiceRequest, Error>`, but it resolves to `<impl BearerFuture as BearerFuture>::Out`
  --> src/server/app.rs:52:69
   |
52 |                 .route(web::post().to(eth::handle_raw_request).wrap(auth))
   |                                                                ---- ^^^^ expected `Result<ServiceRequest, Error>`, found associated type

Comment: maybe related, and more simple, is that I need to be able to call .clone on the result. And that didn't work with your solution.

Comment: Okay, I've edited the post to have more info. I just mean `...` as a placeholder, not as actual syntax. That error has two fixes. You can change the signature of `create_auth_middleware` to return `BearerFuture<Out = Result<ServiceRequest, (Error, ServiceRequest)>>` (there's a mismatch between your `Result` and the one in `HttpAuthentication::bearer` so you might need to fix that). You can also change the trait, which I've done in the edit. For clone, you can simply make the return `impl BearerFuture + Clone`.

Comment: THANKS AGAIN - NOW its truely working. I had figured out about the +Clone thing. But the Out=Result.... change would have taken me MUCH longer to find without your help. NOTE - what you wrote above is wrong on return type - just error not tuple with service request)

Comment: So final code (without traits) is:  pub fn create_auth_middleware() -> HttpAuthentication<BearerAuth, impl BearerFuture<Out = Result<ServiceRequest, Error>>+Clone> {
    let result = HttpAuthentication::bearer(validate_bearer);
    result
}

Comment: My initial reaction here is disappointment with rust. But I will dig further into the details of what you suggested, as there are many kernels which will help me to better understand. Reading the online rust docs - just don't prepare for you for alot of these subtleties ;-)